# How do I write this method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, polygon

The static pointsToPolygon method must take as its parameter an array of Point s, pts. The method must create a new Polygon object that is defined as having the Point s in pts as its points. Your method must return a reference to this new Polygon object.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function funName(...restParam){
  return yourPol;
}
```

The [rest operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) lets you pass unlimited number of arguments as an array.